# Call method for object arrays in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, oop, vectorization

I have an array of objects (of user-defined class), and I want to call a method for all of them. The method represents a processing step for several data channels, tied with treir own objects.

I see two solutions:

1) Writing a for-loop to call method for every object in a vector:

```
for i=1:numel(objArray)
    objArray(i).step;
end
```

2) Adding length check inside class method, like this:

```
function step(obj) 
    if numel(obj)>1
        for i=1:numel(obj)
            step(obj(i));
        end
        return;
    end
    % some processing ...
end
```

But I don't like both solutions, because I should add the same code for every method call in a first case or for every method definition in a second case. 
Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: What is not clear in it? I have 1xN vector of objects and I want to call methods simply by `objArray.step` instead of for-loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical pattern to follow would be something like:

```
function step(objArray)
    for i = 1:numel(objArray)
        % some processing on objArray(i)
    end
end
```

No need for that weird `if` in your question that recursively calls the method on a single element - just do the processing directly on each element.

Comment: Thank you, it is much simpler! I think I should write public methods with this pattern, which vectorize other private methods for a single object. Though in the case of `get` methods this will not work that simple for objects properties.

Comment: You're right that a `get` method is always called on the first element of an array of objects. But you can always use `values = [objArray.value]`: this will call the `get` method for each element of the object array, get the property `value`, and collect them into an array.

Comment: Yes, also I think to maintain the original dimension of object vector and add `out = reshape(out, size(objArray));`